# Working on php/ajax chat system

Tags: php, ajax, events, asynchronous

I have been working on an ajax/php chat system where users can obviously chat with one another. Im concerned about server load, the way it was originally programmed was auto refresh div (chat box) every x seconds it only did this is the user was active as i timed out their inactivity. If they remained inactive for 10 minutes or so they would be shown as idle the system would then stop refreshing. Then i looked into Server-Sent Events with HTML5 which worked well however not all browsers work with this.

Does anyone have a better solution or is the div refresh ok for now? Hope someone can help thanks!

Comment: pre-Web sockets chat systems are going to be auto-refresh hacks one way or another. There's no way around it if you're not going to use Flash/Java for the client.

Comment: The SO chat system pings the server for new messages every second. I find it very responsive. How many users are you expecting?

Comment: Hi thanks guys, i have limited the user limit to 100 at a time.

Comment: If you're willing to stray away from PHP NodeJS + Socket.io is a great combo that supports pretty much every modern browser (and IE6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using COMET, or take a look at Ajax Push Engine: [Link](http://www.ape-project.org)

An example of a chat system using COMET: [Link](http://cheetah.jamieisaacs.com/)

Comment: I ended up using ajax to reload the page every x amount of seconds works good for now and across all browsers so... =]

    var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
  if (!idle) {
   $('#chat-box').load('inc/chat-box.php');
   $('#user-list').load('inc/active-users.php'); // TODO take a look at this <
  }
 }, 5000);'

Answer (score 0):

```js
// jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
});

//jQuery Document
$(document).ready(function(){
 //If user wants to end session
 $("#exit").click(function(){
  var exit = confirm("Are you sure you want to end the session?");
  if(exit==true){window.location = 'index.php?logout=true';}  
 });
});

//If user submits the form
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){
  var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
  $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});    
  $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
  loadLog;
 return false;
});

function loadLog(){  
 var oldscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height before the request
 $.ajax({
  url: "log.html",
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){  
   $("#chatbox").html(html); //Insert chat log into the #chatbox div 
   
   //Auto-scroll   
   var newscrollHeight = $("#chatbox").attr("scrollHeight") - 20; //Scroll height after the request
   if(newscrollHeight > oldscrollHeight){
    $("#chatbox").animate({ scrollTop: newscrollHeight }, 'normal'); //Autoscroll to bottom of div
   }    
    },
 });
}

setInterval (loadLog, 1000);
</script>
```